# Merging 2 pandas DataFrame based on the content of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas DataFrames (`df1`, and `df2`) like this.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['tom', '10'], ['nick', '15'], ['juli', '14']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['name', 'id'])

data2 = [['tom', '59'], ['jane', '20'], ['leo', '17']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['name', 'id'])

# df1
#    name  id
# 0   tom  10
# 1  nick  15
# 2  juli  14

# df2
#    name  id
# 0   tom  59
# 1  jane  20
# 2   leo  17
```

How can I merge them into the following DataFrame?

```
data_merged = [['tom', '10', 'tom', '59'], ['nick', '15', '', ''], ['juli', '14', '', ''],
               ['', '', 'jane', '20'], ['', '', 'leo', '17']]
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(data_merged, columns=['name_1', 'id_1', 'name_2', 'id_2'])

# df_merged
#   name_1 id_1 name_2 id_2
# 0    tom   10    tom   59
# 1   nick   15            
# 2   juli   14            
# 3               jane   20
# 4                leo   17
```

The rule of merge is as follows:

If the content of the `name` column in `df1` and `df2` are identical, they would appear at the same row in `df_merged`.

Otherwise, place the data in different rows of `df_merged`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @BeRT2me - No, partly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) for both DataFrames with outer join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_merged = df1.add_suffix('_1').merge(df2.add_suffix('_2'), 
                                       left_on='name_1', 
                                       right_on='name_2', 
                                       how='outer').fillna('')
print (df_merged)
  name_1 id_1 name_2 id_2
0    tom   10    tom   59
1   nick   15            
2   juli   14            
3               jane   20
4                leo   17
```

If omit `add_suffix` output is different:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer', suffixes=('_1','_2')).fillna('')
print (df_merged)
   name id_1 id_2
0   tom   10   59
1  nick   15     
2  juli   14     
3  jane        20
4   leo        17
```

So used `rename` for 2 columns for `name`s:

```
df_merged=df1.rename(columns={'name':'name_1'}).merge(df2.rename(columns={'name':'name_2'}),
                                                      left_on='name_1', 
                                                      right_on='name_2', 
                                                      how='outer',
                                                      suffixes=('_1','_2')).fillna('')
print (df_merged)
  name_1 id_1 name_2 id_2
0    tom   10    tom   59
1   nick   15            
2   juli   14            
3               jane   20
4                leo   17
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using pandas.concat**

```
import pandas as pd

#reading the csv file into pandas dataframe

df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv')

#Merging two dataframes

merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

#To display the merged dataframe

merged_df
```

> Deprecated function (May Remove in near future, use pandas.concat instead)

**Using dataframe.append**

```
import pandas as pd

#reading the csv file into pandas dataframe

df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv')

#Merging two dataframes

appended_df = df1.append(df2)

#display the merged dataframe

appended_df
```